# AWS Amplify backend build error: invalid command 'egg_info'

Tags: deployment, pip, aws-amplify, pipenv

I'm trying to deploy to AWS amplify, but I'm getting this error on the backend build (I've included some of the preceding logs in case it's helpful):

```
2023-06-29T00:41:53.568Z [WARNING]: created virtual environment CPython3.8.0.final.0-64 in 734ms
                                    creator CPython3Posix(dest=/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/lambdafunction-TMn4ayDM, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
                                    seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/root/.local/share/virtualenv)
                                    added seed packages: pip==23.1.2, setuptools==67.8.0, wheel==0.40.0
                                    activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator
2023-06-29T00:41:53.574Z [WARNING]: ✔ Successfully created virtual environment!
2023-06-29T00:41:53.604Z [WARNING]: Virtualenv location: /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/lambdafunction-tyBXm4FQ
2023-06-29T00:31:41.678Z [INFO]: Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (3a12ae)...
2023-06-29T00:31:41.712Z [WARNING]: usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
                                    or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
                                    or: setup.py --help-commands
                                    or: setup.py cmd --help
                                    error: invalid command 'egg_info'
2023-06-29T00:31:41.811Z [WARNING]: ✖ There was an error initializing your environment.
2023-06-29T00:31:41.812Z [INFO]:  Command failed with exit code 1: pipenv install
```

This was working before, but it started failing after I made some UI changes, which I wouldn't think would be related. I've also tried updating to the latest version of setuptools in the Pipfile within the lambda function directory.

This is the backend section of my my amplify.yml:

```
backend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - ln -fs /usr/local/bin/pip3.8 /usr/bin/pip3
        - ln -fs /usr/local/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3
        - python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
        - python3 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel
        - python3 -m pip install --upgrade pipenv
    build:
      commands:
        - amplifyPush --simple
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're importing setup in your functions setup.py file from distutils.core using:

> from distutils.core import setup

this might be causing the issue as it is out of date, try importing setup from setuptools:

> from setuptools import setup